# How to calculate size of an external array?

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

Does anyone know how to calculate the size of an array from an external file?

Consider:

*Data.c*

```
float arr[]={1.4, 2.3, 7.6, 4.8, 3.3};
```

*Main.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
extern float arr[];
//...
}
```

Then how do I go from there? I've tried using `sizeof` and `size_t` but there are still errors for both methods.

Comment: Please use code formatting when posting code.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from using a `std::vector`.

Comment: @dhke: I don't think that possible duplicate is really a duplicate, because it's about another language.

Comment: Based on your file names, I would say that your code is C, not C++.

Comment: @molbdnilo: The code is valid C++, and is tagged as C++ (or rather, was tagged as C++, before you changed it). Some people use ".c" filename extension for C++ source files. Some people are not aware of the significance of filename extensions.

Comment: @MarcusA: Please confirm which language you're asking about, as there is some doubt (your code is also valid C, and the filename extensions indicate C, rather than the original language tag C++). The solutions differ for C and C++, since they are different languages.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I didn't change the tagging, but I reopened the question when I noticed that I probably dupe-closed it by mistake.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Sorry, my eyes are tricking me today. It's like having water droplets or oil on the glasses. :( I see now the tag was changed by the OP, and then the dupe really is a dupe.

Answer (score 4):

In your main.c file the only information the compiler has is `extern float arr[];` and this doesn't include a size.

So either you try to define a function inside Data.c which returns `sizeof(arr)` (in this compilation unit the size should be known) or, as you tagged the question c++, you use a `std::array` for fixed size or a `std::vector` for variable size.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `extern float arr[]` is an *incomplete type*, it only says that "elsewhere, there is an array called `arr` of unknown size". You can only use `sizeof` if the size is known, for example on `extern float arr[5]`.

However, you should not write programs like this. Using `extern` on non-constant variables is always an indication of bad program design.

Instead, you should use *private encapsulation* and all access to variables should be done through setter/getter functions. Similarly, you can create a function `get_size()` which returns the array size.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, you can't do what you want.  When you say

```
extern float arr[];
```

the compiler simply doesn't have any way of getting the size of that external array.

The simple fix is to use a second global variable that carries the size of the array:

*Data.c*

```
float arr[]={1.4, 2.3, 7.6, 4.8, 3.3};
int arrsz = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
```

*Main.c*

```
extern float arr[];
extern int arrsz;
```

For extra credit, use `size_t arrsz` instead of `int`.

As some other answers have pointed out, though, global variables like this are poor style, especially in "real" programs.  For some higher-style, less-simple fixes, see those other answers.